# regex on key hazelcast

Tags: regex, hazelcast

I am storing data using map data structure in Hazelcast. This will get stored like below:

```
key1 valueforKey1
key2 valueforkey2
key11 valueforKey11
key22 valueforKey22
key123 valueforKey123
key33 valueforKey33
```

Now I want to fetch data on the basis of key from hazelcast, e.g I want all records whose key starts with `key1*`.

How can I do this in hazelcast?

Note: At value I am storing some string.

Comment: not sure about this but you may try  `^key1.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by using the Hazelcast Criteria API http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#criteria-api

Either with ***like*** or ***regex*** directives.

edit:

Here's a complete example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IMap<String, String> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("map-name");

    map.put("key1", "value-1");
    map.put("key21", "value-21");
    map.put("key11", "value-key11");

    SqlPredicate predicate = new SqlPredicate("__key REGEX '^key1.*$'");
    System.out.println(map.values(predicate));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.

this is my code

IMap<String, String> hCTable = client.getMap(tableName);
hCTable.put("key1","valueforKey1");
hCTable.put("key2","valueforkey2");
hCTable.put("key11","valueforKey11");
hCTable.put("key22","valueforKey22");
hCTable.put("key123","valueforKey123");
 
This is how i am storing it in hazelcast.
Now i want to get values which starts with key : key1
It should return all values whose key starts with key1

I don't found anything to do this using link provided by you. If it is possible using above link can you please give me a example?

Comment: `new SqlPredicate("__key REGEX '^key1.*$'");`